# How to view Github user content?

Tags: git, github

I wonder how [this](https://github.com/MarcinKosinski/Museum/blob/master/chaining.html) HTML file stored on a github repository can be viewed as a regular webpage?
Should I change link somehow?

- github.com -> raw.git.com
- github.com -> raw.githubusercontent.com

Those above works somehow but does not show the regular version on webpage.
Thanks for response.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcinKosinski/Museum/master/chaining.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) for that. Your link would be

> https://rawgit.com/MarcinKosinski/Museum/master/chaining.html.

They are not affiliated with GitHub in any way so please be aware of bandwidth restrictions when using the service.

Comment: What's the technical difference between rawgit.com vs raw.githubusercontent.com? Indeed, why would you use rawgit.com over the official raw.githubusercontent.com from GitHub?

Comment: @Pacerier This is the very premise of the question and also mentioned in [rawgit's FAQ](https://rawgit.com/faq). Referring to the original question: If you want to see the HTML, use raw.githubusercontent. If you want to see the rendered HTML in the browser, use rawgit. The technical difference is that the former uses `Content-Type` `text/plain`, the latter uses one depending on the file being served.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, RawGit is shutting down. Therefore, try using [GitHack](https://raw.githack.com/). Your URL would be:

> https://raw.githack.com/MarcinKosinski/Museum/master/chaining.html

And as usual:

> GitHack is not associated with GitHub in any way. Please don't contact their support asking for help with raw.githack.com. They'll give you a weird look and back away slowly.